# A couple of question about Ordinary Least Squares

Tags: analysis, least-squares

I know that if we have the problem of least squares for a system $Ax=y$ there are always solutions.

(I'm interested in the case in which the Hessian matrix $A^TA$ is not positive-definite)

However, are these solutions minimum, or can they be maximum or saddle points? Is there always an absolute minimum? How this can be proved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unconstrained ordinary least squares problem is a convex optimization problem. Therefore, every local minimum is a global minimum, and there are no saddle points or local maxima.  This is true whether or not $A^TA$ is positive definite or is singular; it is always positive semi-definite, thereby giving arise to a convex quadratic objective function.

There will be infinitely many solutions to the ordinary least squares problems if  $A^TA$ is singular.  The minimum 2-norm (of solution vector) is obtained using the pseudo-inverse, pinv, of A, i.e., $x = pinv(A) y$. The other solutions may (or may not) have greater 2-norm, but they all have the same objective value.

Comment: If $A^TA$ is singular as you say there are infinitely many solutions. But you also said that all the solution are local minimum and those are global ones. Is it possible to have infinitely many global minimum without saddle points or local maxima?

Comment: @W4cc0   Yes it is.